# how to download libyaml in windows7 python3.4

Tags: python-3.x, pyyaml

> pip install libyaml
>
> Collecting libyaml   Could not find a version that satisfies the
>
> requirement libyaml (from versions: ) No matching distribution found
>
> for libyaml

Comment: `libyaml` is a C library and cannot be installed from PyPI using `pip`. Why do you want to install that? The windows `.whl` files for my  `ruamel.yaml` include everything you need to use the fast C based loader/dumper, and don't need a separate `libyaml` install.